# Create arraybuffer from large Blob in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, blob, filereader, arraybuffer

I have a simple method for creating arrayBuffer from a blob:

```
 var blob=somehowGetBlob();
 var reader = new FileReader;
 reader.onload = function () {
         onComplete(reader.result);
    };
    reader.onerror = function (err) {
         switch (err.target["error"].code) {
         case err.target["error"].NOT_FOUND_ERR:
              console.log("not found");
              break;
         case err.target["error"].NOT_READABLE_ERR:
              console.log("not read");
              break;
         default:
              console.log("default");
              break;
         };
     };
     reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
```

Everything is normal as it's supposed to be and the reader always triggers its onload event when I ran it in IE11,

In chrome everything is normal if the blob has a small size (I tested it up to 4MB), but when I tested it using 90MB, it always triggers NOT_FOUND_ERR,

Is this normal? or are there some workarounds? or is it just a bug in Chrome?

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Did you check their issue database?

Comment: Did some, but can't find a specific case like this with size

Comment: Sounds like you should try using the power of streams instead, reading up to 90MB RAM is not that desirable especially on phones, try reading/working with the file in chunks?